# how to bundle react to one big bundle with css + js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm trying to build a react app that is dynamically loaded, it should be loaded in different websites like a plugin and on demand.

what I need is first to bundle all the javascript + CSS into one .js file
then it would need to load React + ReactDOM and then inject my app to some placeholder div.

at the moment I'm stuck on disabling create-react-app chunk splitting to multiple js + css files.

Answer (score 0):

in the end solved it with gulp

gulpfile.js:

```
    const gulp = require("gulp");
    const replace = require("gulp-replace");
    const concat = require("gulp-concat");
    const gap = require("gulp-append-prepend");
    const css2js = require("gulp-css2js");
    
    gulp.task("unite-css", () => {
      return gulp
        .src("./build/static/css/*.css")
        .pipe(concat("styles.css"))
        .pipe(css2js({ splitOnNewline: false }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./build/static/js"));
    });
    
    gulp.task("bundle", () => {
      return gulp
        .src("./build/static/js/*.js")
        .pipe(concat("bundle.js"))
        .pipe(replace("ReactDom", "ReactDOM"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/"));
    });
    
    gulp.task("add-react", () => {
      return gulp
        .src("./dist/bundle.js")
        .pipe(gap.prependFile("./react-injector.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
    });
    
    gulp.task("default", gulp.series("unite-css", "bundle", "add-react"));
```

react-injector.js:

```
    function addCdnScript(url) {
      let script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = url;
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
    addCdnScript("https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js");
    addCdnScript("https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js");
```

of course you still need a `<div id="root"/>` in your dom to inject.